# How to add react-leaflet map to remixjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, remix.run

I'm trying to add a `react-leaflet` map to a remix app.  I created a simple app using the `npx create-remix@latest` command.  I then added `react-leaflet` using the [installation instructions](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-installation/).  Now I have the following code:

index.tsx

```
import type { MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { ClientOnly } from "remix-utils/client-only";
import LazyMap from "~/components/LazyMap";

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
  return [
    { title: "New Remix App" },
    { name: "description", content: "Welcome to Remix!" },
  ];
};

export default function Index() {
  return (
      <div>
        test 123
        <ClientOnly fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          {() => <LazyMap />}
        </ClientOnly>
      </div>
  );
}
```

LazyMap.tsx

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
const Map = lazy(() => import('./Map'));

export default function LazyMap() {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <Map />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

Map.tsx

```
import { MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet/MapContainer'
// import { Marker } from 'react-leaflet/Marker'
// import { Popup } from 'react-leaflet/Popup'
// import { TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet/TileLayer'
import { ClientOnly } from 'remix-utils/client-only';


export default function Map() {
    return (
        <div>
            test 123
            <ClientOnly>
              {() => (
                <MapContainer zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
                  test
                </MapContainer>
              )}
            </ClientOnly>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Even though I've wrapped the `Map` in a lazy import from `LazyMap` it appears to still be trying to process the `Map` file, which of course references leaflet and causes the dreaded `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error.  How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Did you try https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/server-vs-client#client-modules? It's entirely possibly that just *importing* the map code causes a reference window, you need to exclude it entirely from the SSR not just wrap it in a util component.

Comment: That was it.  Add this as an answer and I'll mark it.  Thank you!

Comment: Done. Glad you got it sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClientOnly` utility is great when *rendering* the component causes a reference to some client-side-only global variable like `window` or `document`, but it can only wrap component code you've imported, and imports can have side-effects...like referencing `window` or `document`.

According to the [official remix docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/server-vs-client#client-modules) you can add a `.client.ts/tsx/js/jsx` suffix to your file to have it excluded from the SSR.